# How to Insert Item into Javascript Hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the first hash is

```
a = {"10167": "Hello", "10122": "World", "10245": "Hello2", "10035": "People"}
```

second hash is

```
b = {"A": "one", "B": "10122", "C": "Three"}
```

I want to get like the following:

```
b = {"A": "one", "B": "10122", "B_Description": "World", "C": "Three"}
```

Whenever the hash `a` key appears in hash `b` value, I want to insert a new item next to that.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to solve your problem yourself?

Comment: There is nothing like „next to that” in JavaScript objects (#JS has not hashes)

Comment: @hindmost Thanks for your comment. Yes I have been tried a lot of different ways and failed in each way.

Comment: @Sri please - show your effort and ways how you want to solve that problem

Comment: Got already 4 downvotes. So dont bother. Thanks for your effort mate.

Comment: There is no hashes in JavaScript, you are using objects in your question, also the object values can not be sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in looping over the keys and elements of each object. When a match is found, add it. http://jsfiddle.net/2x6Lws96/1/

```
var a = {"10167":"Hello", "10122":"World", "10245":"Hello2", "10035":"People"};
var b = {"A": "one", "B": "10122", "C": "Three"};

var akeys = Object.keys(a);

for(bkey in b) {
    if(a[b[bkey]]) {
        b[bkey+'_Description'] = a[b[bkey]];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This will only work in IE9 and above (and pretty much any other browser) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

In JS you dont 'insert' values into objects. Just assign them `myObject.newField = 'newValue'`

**EDIT 2**

Updated as per Felix's suggestions

Comment: What's the purpose of `bclone`? Note that you don't need `Object.keys` at all. `akeys.indexOf(bclone[bkey]) != -1` could be simplified to `a[bclone[bkey]] != null`. You can simply lookup whether the property exists.

Comment: Too right @FelixKling .. the bclone thing was because i have been doing too much C# lately and it hates when you modify a collection while iterating it.

Comment: Hi, what is 'bkey'? I got 'bkey' is undefined. @michaelcoxon

Comment: `bkey` is the key in the object. ie in `b` they are `A`,`B`, `C`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var a = {"10167": "Hello", "10122": "World", "10245": "Hello2", "10035": "People"};
var b = {"A": "one", "B": "10122", "C": "Three"};

for(var prop in b) {
    var val = a[b[prop]];
    if(val != undefined) {
        b[prop + '_Description'] = val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're able to use a library, there are plenty of good solutions, including [lodash's assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign).

If you want to do this on your own, you can iterate over the keys of the source object and insert the values into the destination:

```
Object.keys(a).forEach(function (key) {
    b[key] = a[key];
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. Is it possible to use this in Underscore.js?

Comment: This doesn't produce the result the OP wants.

Comment: @FelixKling you're totally right. I answered too quickly.